# Как лучше уйти от Servletov в java

Tags: java, servlet

До этого момента в работе не сталкивался с сервлетами. Есть легаси код в монолите на java7. Передача данных идет через xml. Синхронизация и взаимодействие осуществляется через Сервлеты. Планируется рефакторинг проекта и переход на микросервисы. Подскажите как лучше уйти от сервлетов, но чтобы остался обмен данных через xml. И желательно ссылки, что можно почитать на эту тему?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: На вопрос в такой формулировке нельзя дать ответ. Приведу аналогию. "У нас транспортная компания делает изменение структуры. Подскажите как уйти от использования автомобилей?" Конечно есть другие возможности (в аналогии ЖД транспорт, самолеты даже велосипеды) и у каждой своя область применения, но не понимая причину, почему именно "уходите от сервлетов", что конкретно это означает, и по каким критериям будут оцениваться альтернативы - ответ дать нельзя.